# text box / input form that parses html?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, input

how can I make a text box or any input form parse html? Im building a message section, and In the "To" input box I am trying to design an automatic contact inserter type function, which will use a jquery keyup  function to send user data to a php script, and it will return the appropriate contact (or a list of contacts below which will load the appropriate one when the user clicks on it) in a small div in the box(which can be styled). I did a horrible job of phrasing  what I was trying to do, so if you dont understand (im amazed if you do) overall my questions is how to make a textbox/input form parse html?

Comment: Try to use some characters to make Words bold and italic... For Example Gmail chat * Bold * _ italic _ and in stackoverflow [ link ](http://google.com) _ italic _ ** bold ** ` code `. Or You want to make Yahoo Msger way then you have to convert Div as textbox using keypress event in javascript...

Comment: sounds like you want tinymce.com or  ckeditor.com

Comment: im actually using ckeditor for the main message, but i think its a tad too big for the to section, how could I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you should read, `.keyup()` event of the jquery will help you the detect the user input, the basic structure here it is:

```
$('#id').keyup(function(){
var data = $(this).val();

//now you use ajax request
$.ajax({
  url: 'yourphpfile.php',
  data: 'data=' + data,
  success: function(callback){}
});
});
```

this is just a basic example for more you should go to the jquery.com

Comment: i meant use keyup then a post function

Comment: @roozbubu, use keyup to detect the user input and pass that input to your php file through ajax request and the above callback return you the data of your php file. You can expand it as more if you can. with css styles or with .click event

Comment: this is for if you want more then one contacts, and you want click event on that contacts

Comment: i understand how to do this this is the easy part. my problem is Im trying to parse html in an input field, is this possible?

Comment: @roozbubu, well i am not sure about this but .html() might be help you.